# Targeting elements to show/hide based on matching ids and classes

Tags: jquery

Very new to Jquery and wondering if anyone can help me with the following problem:

Using Textpattern I have a list generated as so;

```
<li class="archive-month"><a href="#" id="May2011">May</a></li>
<li class="May2011"><a rel="bookmark" href="http://***">Post Number One</a></li>
<li class="May2011"><a rel="bookmark" href="http://***">Post Number Two</a></li>
<li class="May2011"><a rel="bookmark" href="http://***">Post Number One</a></li>    
<li class="archive-month"><a href="#" id="April2011">April</a></li>
```

ad infinitum.

My question is, how can I use the `<a>` tags to show and hide the list items with classes that match the id of the tag? For example, click on the `a` with an id of "May2011" to toggle hiding and showing of all `li` with a matching class of "May2011" and so on for the various months.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To present an alternative solution which *should* be more efficient than [@David's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206381/targeting-elements-to-show-hide-based-on-matching-ids-and-classes/6206411#6206411):

```
$('li.archive-month > a').live('click', function()
{
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('.archive-month').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

You can even do a bit better by using `.delegate()` instead of `.live()` if all the `<li>`s share a common ancestor - a `<ul>`, perhaps.

```
$('#some-common-ancestor').delegate('li.archive-month > a', 'click', function()
{
    $(this).parent().nextUntil('.archive-month').toggle();
    return false;
});
```

**N.B.** this does not use element IDs at all. Instead it relies on the HTML structure being consistent with what's in the OP — namely that the `<li>`s that should be toggled when a link is clicked are the next siblings of the parent of the link, up to but not including the next `li` with class `archive-month`.

Comment: Well, I'll +1 efficiencies... :)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you both very much. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

You could try:

```
$('a').click(
    function(){
        var elemClass = this.id;
        $('li.' + elemClass).toggle();
        return false; // assuming you don't want to follow the link.
    });
```

References:

- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: [`class` is a future reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words#Future_reserved_words), so not a great idea to use it as a variable name. At any rate, why would you not inline that? `$('li.' + this.id).hide();`

Comment: +1 Well since I already did the fiddle with close to the same solution Ill just post it here, http://jsfiddle.net/qVWgF/1/

Comment: @Matt, yeah...I forgot that `class` was reserved (and revised prior to seeing your comment, but thanks!) and, as to not in-lining? Mainly to make it more clear what I was doing. But in-line, as per @Loktar's (deleted) answer, would be preferred.

Comment: You should change `$('a')` to `$('a[id]')`, so only tags with IDs are selected.

Comment: @Rocket, I *could* sure, but I left it to the OP to supply the appropriate selector. But, for specificity and efficiency, I've up-voted [@Matt Ball's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206381/targeting-elements-to-show-hide-based-on-matching-ids-and-classes/6206507#6206507).