# how to hide content of the link in the same page?

Tags: html, blogger

I am trying to create a blog page. In my blog page, I want give a link to the place on the same page. How can I do that with html ?

```
Ex sort of table of the content

   |------------------------------|
   |  List of smt                 |
   |     *X                       |
   |     *Y                       |
   |     *Z                       |
   |     *T                       |
   |------------------------------|
```

when user pres one of the link such as X, the same page will be loaded with content of the X .
       content of the X

```
   |------------------------------|
   |           X                  |
   |   X is .....                 |
   | .......................      |
   | .. . X is used in .....      |
   |------------------------------|
```

Comment: I have tried the <a href="<url>"> <name></a>

Comment: I'm really not 100% sure what you're asking... sounds like you're after a simple `<a name="taglink"></a>` with `<a href="#taglink">X</a>`

Comment: I am trying give a list of the title. Then, if user pushes one of them, same page will be loaded with  content. In other words, I am trying to store content with link in the same page. Content is hiding behind the link.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this would be helpful to you, however you could do it with some CSS ?

If you have everything on one page you can make divs with id's and then link to each ID and it will scroll down to that... You could have the divs hidden off the page and when clicked they appear...

If that sounds useful I can provide some code

CODE: So as far as I understand, you want to link to a different part of the page (most likely further down)

Here's an option and let me know if it is valid to your question:

```
{CSS}
#partofpage {



}


{HTML}
<a href = "#partofpage">Link</a>
```

If you wanted to hide a div or make it visible:

```
{CSS}
#partofpagehidden {

visibily : hidden; /*if you put "Collapse" then it would hide a column/row of a table*/
OR

display: none; /*This would take the element away and it wont take up any space,      visibility would take it away but it would take up the same space*/




}
#partofpageshown {

visibility: visible;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?49019-jQuery-hide()-and-show()-based-on-a-select-element

[Targeting elements to show/hide based on matching ids and classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6206381/targeting-elements-to-show-hide-based-on-matching-ids-and-classes)

```
<HEAD>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#bloc").change(function() {

    if ($("#bloc").val() == 2)
    {
        $("#bdays, #bdays2, #brea, #brea2").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {      
        $("#bdays, #bdays2, #brea, #brea2").hide();
    }

    });

    if ($("#bloc").val() == 2)
    {
        $("#bdays, #bdays2, #brea, #brea2").show("fast");
    }
    else
    {      
        $("#bdays, #bdays2, #brea, #brea2").hide();
    }

});
 </script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<select id="bloc">
<option value="1">Normal</option>
<option value="2">Blocked</option>
</select>

<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>value 1</td>
        <td>value 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="bdays">
            Days:
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="bdays2">
            <input type="text" id="VIN" value="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="brea">
            Reason:
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div id="brea2">
            <input type="text" id="VIN" value="">
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</BODY>
```

Try this out.